# 'to_field_name' argument on a ModelChoiceField() doesn't seem to be working

Tags: django, django-forms

Well, pretty much what it says in the title.

I'm creating a `ModelChoiceField()` in one of my `Forms`, like so:

```
class FormCreatePlace(forms.ModelForm):
    (...)
    category = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.all(), to_field_name='name')
    (...)
```

The `Category` model is defined like so:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
```

And yet the field itself on the HTML form insists on displaying the primary keys (a series of UUIDs) as the choices.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `to_field_name` is used to change the value of the options, not the displayed text

The easiest way to change the displayed text is to change the `__str__` method on your model to return the `name` field:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

However, that will affect how the categories are displayed elsewhere. If you don't want to do that, you can subclass `ModelChoiceField` and override `label_from_instance`.

```
class MyModelChoiceField(ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return obj.name
```

Then use your choice field in the form.

```
class FormCreatePlace(forms.ModelForm):
    (...)
    category = forms.MyModelChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.all())
```

See the [`ModelChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) docs for more info.

Comment: A fantastic response with good advice, since changing `__str__` on my model would have had implications elsewhere. Thank you Alasdair.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. They should really make a new argument for the displayname. The default displayname is not user friendly, so not many will use that.

Comment: @user3042674 [Here's the thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/django-developers/bMccEyzlnC0/glPkTDz6AgAJ) on the Django developer's mailing list about adding an argument to model choice field.

Comment: This caused me so much pain and the subclass of ```ModelChoiceField``` is just inspired.  So thank you Alasdair! Amazing the Django devs haven't applied the changes discussed in that thread