# Django form not populating with POST data

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

**Problem:** Django form is populating with list of **objects** rather than **values**

**Summary:** I have 2 models *Entities* and *Breaks*. *Breaks* has a FK relationship to the *entity_id* (not the PK) on the *Entities* model.

I want to generate an empty form for all the fields of *Breaks*. Generating a basic form populates all the empty fields, but for the FK it generates a dropdown list of all **objects** of the *Entities* table. This is not helpful so I have excluded this in the ModelForm below and tried to replace with a list of all the **entity_ids** of the *Entities* table. This form renders as expected.

```
class BreakForm(ModelForm):   
    class Meta:
        model = Breaks
        #fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ('entity',)
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):        
        super(BreakForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)         
        self.fields['entity_id'] = ModelChoiceField(queryset=Entities.objects.all().values_list('entity_id', flat=True))
```

The below FormView is the cbv called by the URL. As the below stands if I populate the form, and for the FK column **entity_id** choose one of the values, the form will not submit. By that field on the form template the following message appears *Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices*.

```
class ContactFormView(FormView):
    template_name = "breaks/test/breaks_form.html"
    form_class = BreakForm
```

My initial thoughts were either that the datatype of this field (string/integer) was wrong or that  Django needed the PK of the row in the *Entities* table (for whatever reason).

So I added a post function to the FormView and could see that the request.body was populating correctly. However I can't work out how to populate this into the ModelForm and save to the database, or overcome the issue mentioned above.

Addendum:

Models added below:

```
class Entity(models.Model):
    pk_securities = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    entity_id = models.CharField(unique=True)
    entity_description = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True)
    
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'entities'
    
    
class Breaks(models.Model):
    pk_break = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)    
    entity = models.ForeignKey(Entity, on_delete= models.CASCADE, to_field='entity_id')  
    commentary = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True)
    active = models.BooleanField()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse(
            "item-update", args=[str(self.pk_break)]
        )

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.pk_break}"

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'breaks'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION

Firstly I got this working by adding the following to the Entity Model class. However I didn't like this as it would have consequences elsewhere.

```
def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.entity_id}"
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49114304/to-field-name-argument-on-a-modelchoicefield-doesnt-seem-to-be-working) SO thread on the topic. The accepted answer is fantastic and the comments to it are helpful. The solution is to subclass ModelChoiceField and override the label_from_instance

```
class EntityChoiceField(ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return obj.entity_id
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is two fold, first is not rendering the dropdown correctly and second is form is not saving. For first problem, you do not need to do any changes in `ModelChoiceField` queryset, instead, add [`to_field_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField.to_field_name):

```
class BreakForm(ModelForm):   
    class Meta:
        model = Breaks
        #fields = '__all__'
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):        
        super(BreakForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)         
        self.fields['entity_id'] = ModelChoiceField(queryset=Entities.objects.all(), to_field_name='entity_id')
```

Secondly, if you want to save the form, instead of FormView, use [`CreateView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#createview):

```
class ContactFormView(CreateView):
    template_name = "breaks/test/breaks_form.html"
    form_class = BreakForm
    model = Breaks
```

Comment: Thanks but when I change the ModelChoiceField to your suggested one - in the dropdown options are just a list of objects i.e. Entity Object (PK) rather than a list of the entity_ids (which is why I was making changes to ModelChoiceField

Comment: It didn't change after adding to_field_name?

Comment: No. To get a list of the entity_ids I needed to add those changes to ModelChoices. I have posted at the bottom of the post the models in case that helps

Comment: Thanks for your help Ruddra. I got there in the end through a different method. It seems the ModelChoiceField doesn't have an argument to change the labelling